# Integrate Akamai with graphite

Tags: cdn, graphite, grafana, akamai

I have an object delivery service on Akamai and i would like to fetch the usage data for our endpoints and send it to graphite and create some graphs on grafana.

so appreciate any suggestions or ideas to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

We have built a [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) exporter for Akamai data, the [cloudmonitor_exporter](https://github.com/ExpressenAB/cloudmonitor_exporter). If you couple this with the [graphite_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/graphite_exporter), you should be able to get the data into Graphite (albeit a bit roundabout). If you want to go directly to Graphite, you can probably pick up some inspiration from how we built it for Prometheus.

(Note: This requires that you have the "Cloud Monitor" product in your Akamai account)

Comment: thank you! i'm already aware of this solution but it will cost us a lot of money so i'm looking for something free or not too expensive

Comment: Ah. Well, in that case what are your latency requirements? The only other way to get the full request logs from Akamai is using their log delivery (which I _think_ is free), but that has a fairly long latency: logs are delivered every hour.

Comment: If you do not require the full log data, you could potentially do some form of API integration with Akamai, depending on what you need. The list of APIs is here: https://developer.akamai.com/api.